# How to put a dictionary in a JSON?

Tags: python, json, rest, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I'm working with a REST API, and I need to return a `JSON` with my values ​​to it. However, I need the `items` of the payload variable to show all the items inside the `cart_item`.

I have this:

```py
payload = {
    "items": [],
}
```

I tried this, but I don't know how I would put this inside the `items` of the payload:

```py
for cart_item in cart_items:
    item = [
        {
            "reference_id": f"{cart_item.sku}",
            "name": f"{cart_item.product.name}",
            "quantity": cart_item.quantity,
            "unit_amount": cart_item.product.price
        },
     ]
```

I need you to get back to me:

```
payload = {
    "items": [ 
        {
            "reference_id": "SKU49FS20DD",
            "name": "Produto 1",
            "quantity": 1,
            "unit_amount": 130
        },
        {
            "reference_id": "SKU42920SSD",
            "name": "Produto 2",
            "quantity": 1,
            "unit_amount": 100
        }
    ],
}

response = requests.request(
    "POST",
    url,
    headers=headers,
    json=payload
)
```

I don't know if I would need to pass what's in `JSON` to the dictionary to change and then send it to `JSON` again.

Comment: at the end of for loop why not just do `payload["items"] = item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing the "[append()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/append)" method on a list, and the conversion from [Python list & dict to a JSON string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```
 from json import dumps

 items_dict = []
 for cart_item in cart_items:
            items_dict.append({
                "reference_id": f"{cart_item.sku}",
                "name": f"{cart_item.product.name}",
                "quantity": cart_item.quantity,
                "unit_amount": cart_item.product.price
             })

payload = {
    'items': items_dict
}

# And if you want a JSON string as output
print(dumps(payload))
```

But you don't need a string to the "json" argument in requests.post, so you can keep your

```
response = requests.request(
    "POST",
    url, 
    headers=headers,
    json=payload
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to create one item at a time, just populate `payload['items']` directly, using a comprehension:

```py
payload['items'] = [
    {
        'reference_id': cart_item.sku,
        'name': cart_item.product.name,
        'quantity': cart_item.quantity,
        'unit_amount': cart_item.product.price 
    }
    for cart_item in cart_items
]
```

Another possible improvement is about `requests`. Instead of using `requests.requests('POST' ...)`, you can use `requests.post(...)`.

And finally, if the API really needs `json` to have a valid `JSON` string, use `json.dumps` to convert it.

Putting all together:

```py
import requests
import json

payload['items'] = [
    {
        'reference_id': cart_item.sku,
        'name': cart_item.product.name,
        'quantity': cart_item.quantity,
        'unit_amount': cart_item.product.price 
    }
    for cart_item in cart_items
]

response = requests.post(
    url,
    headers=headers,
    json=json.dumps(payload)
)
```

Even though I'm almost a hundred percent sure `requests.post()` will do the right thing if you just pass the `payload` as is in `json=payload`.